# Hide a given combining character from HTML

Tags: css, unicode, fonts, font-face, combining-marks

I have HTML that contains text with accent marks (U+0301 - a combining character) to denote stress. I'd like to be able to show and hide the accents with a checkbox. Some of the HTML is dynamically generated.

Is there a way to do this with CSS only? (no JavaScript and no enclosing all occurrences of U+0301 in tags)

One idea I tried was to use a custom font that renders U+0301 as an empty glyph - it does hide U+0301 in isolation, but fails to hide it when it's combined with another character.

Comment: looks like `U+0301` when combines with other characters, becomes a different character altogether. You'll need a font family to render `Á` as `A`. But I am not sure if such a font-family is present.